# How can I generate 2 random numbers? Why doesn't my method work?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm currently trying to learn JavaScript and wanted to write a program that generates 2 random integers. My attempt was as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Generate</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

        function myFunction() 
        {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x ", " y;
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, this does not work. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? It works when I only have x, but not when I have x and y.

Comment: `x  + ", " + y`, notice `+`.

Comment: Tip: open your browser Console (press F12) to see the Javascript errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Generate</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

        function myFunction() 
        {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + ", " + y;
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem was:

> x ", " y

Right way:

> x + ", " + y